# Keycloak get user password

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-rest-api

In my project, I need to get current user password from Rest API.

I searched keycloak 4.8.3 final documentation but I could not find it.  With admin user I can change password without knowing the current password. But my logged in user can be admin or not. I found that keycloak does not give me permission to that because of security. Wrap up is there any way to active that settings or is there a way to get password with Rest API ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Update:** The `/auth` path was removed starting with [Keycloak 17 Quarkus distribution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71902419/1366871). So you might need to remove the `/auth` from the endpoint calls presented on this answer.

---

Via the Rest API, one cannot get the password for obvious reasons. Ideally, in a secure setting, even if one is the admin one should not have access to the users' passwords.

From the comments you wrote:

> I could use method like boolean isPasswordCorrect(username,password)

An approach is to create a client on your Realm as follows:

- Go to your Realm;
- Clients;
- Create Client;
- Set `Access Type` to public;
- Set `Direct Access Grants Enabled` to ON;
- Save;

Now request from the newly created client a token on behalf of the user that you want to check if the password is correct:

[image]

As you can see the endpoint is:

```
<KEYCLOAK_HOST>/auth/realms/<REALM_NAME/protocol/openid-connect/token
```

and the body is:

```
client_id : <The client ID of the newly create client>
username : <The username>
password : <The password to be tested>
grant_type : password
```

If the password is correct you will get back a token object, otherwise you will get the following response:

```
{
    "error": "invalid_grant",
    "error_description": "Invalid user credentials"
}
```

Comment: If there were any pending actions like update password or configure otp then this will return 
`{
    "error": "invalid_grant",
    "error_description": "Account is not fully set up"
}`